# Touch event on awesomium webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

By default `awesomium` in WPF application doesn't support touch event for zoom and panning:

```
  browserLeft.StylusDown += browserLeft_StylusDown;
  browserLeft.TouchDown += browserLeft_TouchDown;
```

I want to manipulate browser by myself, but none of the code wont occur touches, why?

Comment: Have you tried trapping the gestures in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this yet? If so please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Look @ http://wiki.awesomium.net/wpf/user-input.html "When using the WPF WebControl, it is the WebViewPresenter and not the WebControl itself that handles user input. This means that handling user input related events on the WebControl, will not prevent the WebViewPresenter from handling these events and passing them to the native view." Hope this is the problem